# Defining two variable in one line, as opposed to 2 lines

Tags: python-2.7

I am new-ish to Python and was interested if putting code on one line (as opposed to many) is always the way to go.

For example, the two code snippets below do exactly the same thing, but the first one has cut out 1 line of code. Is this considered 'un-pythonic'?

```
mean1, var1 = np.mean(value), np.var(value)
```

Or..

```
mean1 = np.mean(value)
var1 = np.var(value)
```

Comment: you could also do `mean1 = np.mean(value); var1 = np.var(value)`. unpacking is not necessary here because you don't have a tuple in the first place. You _build_ a tuple to unpack to 2 variables. I'd do the second approach.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a recommended way of doing it, or is it person preference?

Comment: Ah okay. That sort of makes sense. I will just go with the second approach.

Comment: You can use whatever approach you want, From my point my view both approaches make sense. I normally use second approach, as it is more understandable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That construct:

```
a,b = c
```

is particularly useful to *unpack* `c` which is known as a collection/iterable made of 2 elements.

The usefulness of that:

```
mean1, var1 = np.mean(value), np.var(value)
```

is dubious: you create a `tuple` on the right side just to be able to unpack it on the left side. If the effect is a one-liner, you could as well do this:

```
mean1 = np.mean(value); var1 = np.var(value)
```

so you don't create any extra temp object.

Comment: Thanks! That's useful to know.